# Optimize time iteration in python for encoding labels

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have these columns in a python's dataframe, named admission:

```
Patient ID, Regular ward, Semi-intensive, Intensive
1                0               0            0
2                1               0            0
3                0               1            0
4                0               1            0
5                0               0            1
```

I´ve already done the following transformation:

```
 Patient ID, Admission type
 1                 0
 2                 1
 3                 2
 4                 2
 5                 3
```

Basically, to reach this transformation, I create a new column called 'No admission' containing 1 if the three columns (Regular ward, Semi-intensive, Intensive) are 0, else it returns 0.

After that, I have mapped the values in each column into one column to return the name of column, instead of 0 or 1.

```
Patient ID, Admission type
 1          No admission
 2          Regular ward
 3          Semi-intensive
 4          Semi-intensive
 5          Intensive
```

And make the mapping again for No admission=0, Regular ward=1, Semi-intensive=2, Intensive=3

Here is my full code transformation.

```
df['No admission'] = None
admission= df.iloc[:,3:6] # Selecting only the three columns mentioned above.

for row in df.index:
    if admission.apply(any,axis=1).values[row]:
        df.loc[row,'No admission'] = 0
    else:
        df.loc[row,'No admission'] = 1

cols = [4,5,6,106]
df.insert(loc = 1,
          column = 'Admission type',
          value = df.iloc[:,cols].apply(np.argmax, axis=1))

df.drop(df.columns[cols],axis=1,inplace=True)

le = LabelEncoder()
le.fit(df['Admission type'])
df['Admission type'] = le.transform(df['Admission type'])
```

The point is: my original dataset has 5644 rows and 111 columns. The time execution to explain what I mentioned above is about 10 minutes!

I know that is a better way to improve it, and I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does using `np.where()` improve the performance? I imagine it would be much faster.

Input:

```
Patient ID  Regular ward   Semi-intensive  Intensive
1                0               0            0
2                1               0            0
3                0               1            0
4                0               1            0
5                0               0            1
```

Code:

```
df=pd.read_clipboard(sep='\\s\\s+'))
df['Admission type'] = ''
df['Admission type'] = np.where(df['Regular ward'] == 1, 'Regular ward', df['Admission type'])
df['Admission type'] = np.where(df['Semi-intensive'] == 1, 'Semi-intensive', df['Admission type'])
df['Admission type'] = np.where(df['Intensive'] == 1, 'Intensive', df['Admission type'])
df['Admission type'] = np.where((df['Regular ward'] + df['Semi-intensive'] + df['Intensive'] == 0),
                              'No admission', df['Admission type'])
df=df[['Patient ID', 'Admission type']]
df
```

Output:

```
    Patient ID   Admission type
0   1          No admission
1   2          Regular ward
2   3          Semi-intensive
3   4          Semi-intensive
4   5          Intensive
```

Comment: Great answer. Worked for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
admission_copy = admission.copy()
admission_copy["Semi-intensive"] = admission_copy["Semi-intensive"]*2
admission_copy["Intensive"] = admission_copy["Intensive"]*3
df["Admission type"] = admission_copy.sum(axis=1)
```

This is assuming that there are no patients with two types of admission types. If you only need the regular, semi, and intensive columns to create this column, you don't have to copy the df you can just change df directly.

Edit: Also, I assumed "patient" is the index column. If it is its own column, simply don't include it as part of your "admission" df slice and it should still work

Answer (score 0):

You may use `dot` to merge column names into each `1` and create a new dataframe from it.

```
df1 = df[['Regular-ward', 'Semi-intensive', 'Intensive']]
df_final = df[['Patient_ID']].assign(**{'Admission Type': df1.dot(df1.columns).replace('', 'No admission')})

Out[16]:
   Patient_ID  Admission Type
0           1   No admission
1           2    Regular-ward
2           3  Semi-intensive
3           4  Semi-intensive
4           5       Intensive
```

Answer (score 0):

Idea is create index by first column, so is possible use matrix multiplication by all columns by [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) and replace empty strings by `No admission`, last convert index to column:

```
df = df.set_index('Patient ID')
df = df.dot(df.columns).replace('','No admission').reset_index(name='Admission type')
print (df)
   Patient ID  Admission type
0           1    No admission
1           2    Regular ward
2           3  Semi-intensive
3           4  Semi-intensive
4           5       Intensive
```

Similar idea with filter all columns without first:

```
s = df.iloc[:, 1:].dot(df.columns[1:]).replace('','No admission').rename('Admission type')
df = df.iloc[:, [0]].join(s)
```

If possible multiple `1` per rows solution is changed with add separator to columns names and [`Series.str.rstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html):

```
print (df)
   Patient ID  Regular ward  Semi-intensive  Intensive
0           1             0               0          0
1           2             1               0          1
2           3             0               1          0
3           4             0               1          0
4           5             0               0          1


df = df.set_index('Patient ID')
df = (df.dot(df.columns + ',')
        .str.rstrip(',')
        .replace('','No admission')
        .reset_index(name='Admission type'))
print (df)
   Patient ID          Admission type
0           1            No admission
1           2  Regular ward,Intensive
2           3          Semi-intensive
3           4          Semi-intensive
4           5               Intensive
```